# Passing Value from string.xml from one Fragment to another activity?

Tags: android

The value in **string.xml** file is.

`<string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>`

From this Fragment i am trying to pass value to another activity ... by using `putextra`

`i=new Intent(Basic.this.getContext(),DisplayBasicData.class);
 i.putExtra("header", R.string.action_settings);
 startActivity(i);`

Then i try to get value using

`String text_point = getIntent().getStringExtra("header");`

But it not getting the value.

Comment: why are you sending string file value from one activity to another. You can access your string value anywhere in your app  by referencing it . It is foolish to passing String files values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `Bundle` :

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("header", getResources().getString(R.string.action_settings));
i=new Intent(Basic.this.getContext(),DisplayBasicData.class);
i.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(i);
```

and extract in `DisplayBasicData` activity:

`String text_point = getIntent().getExtras().getString("header")`;

Comment: Thanks for this solution

Answer (score 0):

You are sending resource id ,not string

Here you can get string in two ways :

**First way:**

```
i.putExtra("header", R.string.action_settings);

int text_pointResourceId = getIntent().getIntExtra("header");
String text_point = getResources().getString(text_pointResourceId)
```

**secondWay:**

```
i.putExtra("header", getResources().getString(R.string.action_settings));
String text_point = getIntent().getStringExtra("header");
```

Hope it helps

Instead of sending data directly , it is better to use `Bundle`

Comment: Thanks for this solution

Comment: Yes they will , But using `Bundle` is recommended if you want to avoid complex problems in future.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass that string simply in following way, no need of putting data in bundle.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayBasicData.class);
String myText = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.action_settings);
intent.putExtra("header", myText);
startActivity(intent);
```

then you can retrieve that data by using

```
String text_header = getIntent().getStringExtra("header");
```